# Trust gpg key via script

Tags: linux, bash, automation, gpg

When performing an automated server deployment, I can upload and import gpg keys via script. But I cannot trust keys.

I tried

```sh
gpg --batch --yes --edit-key keyname trust 5
```

and

```sh
echo 5 | gpg --batch --yes --edit-key keyname trust -
```

In non-batch mode it always stops to ask for input. In batch mode it ignores input.

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

get fingerprint for key `"keyname"`:
`FP=$(gpg --list-keys keyname | head -n2 | tail -n1 | tr -d '[:blank:]')`

trust key:
`echo -e "5\ny\n" | gpg --command-fd 0 --edit-key "$FP" trust`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ fingerprint=`gpg --fingerprint --with-colons b@gmail.com \
    | awk -F: '/^pub:/ {getline; print $10}'`
$ gpg --quick-sign-key "$b_fingerprint"
```

Determining a fingerprint is taken from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/673230/gpg2-get-fingerprint-using-script/673300#673300). A bigger example can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/9fe9e7c46d75a75690c6c5ecdf441f79).